# Keras tensorflow Model not returning Map with UserDefined Keynames

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

I am new to Keras API , I am able to get Map as response but i am not able to get userdefined key names in response For Ex: My Expected response is

```
{
    "predictions": [
        {
            "outputKeyVal": [
                24.0
            ],
            "outputKeyStr": "O1"
        }
}
```

My Actual response is

```
{
    "predictions": [
        {
            "map_script_1": [
                24.0
            ],
            "map_script": "O1"
        }
}
```

I am expecting userdefined key names such as "outputKeyVal","outputKeyStr" instead i get only "map_script_1","map_script"

Here are the details about my Model:

I am using Keras Functional API for saving the tensor model and using predict method for retrieving the model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras

class MapScript(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(MapScript, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.a_weight = self.add_weight(
            'a_weight',
            initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(20.00),
            dtype=tf.dtypes.float64,
            trainable=False)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):
        inputStr = tf.squeeze(inputs['inputStr'])
        inputVal = inputs['inputVal']
        outputVal = tf.add(inputVal,self.a_weight)
        return { "outputKeyVal": outputVal , "outputKeyStr": inputStr}


#Set keras backend to use float64 for unspecified dtypes. Default is float32
keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

#Set number of features in Input
inputs = {
    "inputVal":keras.Input(shape=(1,),name="inputVal"),
    "inputStr":keras.Input(shape=(1,),name="inputStr", dtype=tf.string)
}

#Define number of layers
outputs = ThirdScript(1)(inputs)

#Configure the model
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

#Save the model. To save with other version tags, create a directory in the saved_model_score model location with appropriate version number before running the script
keras.models.save_model(model,'../../../../../../resources/models/saved_model_score/1',overwrite=True,include_optimizer=True,save_format=None,options=None)
```